# how to replace cell values in a column of a data frame at a specified frequency with the previous cell value?

Tags: python

There is one column
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
Output should be:
1
1
1
1
5
5
5
5
9
9
9
9
13
13
13
13
17
17
17
17

Unable to solve the same

how to replace every 3 cell values in a column with its previous cell value in a data frame in python. I am trying to replace the cell values in a specified frequency with its previous cell value.
Please help to resolve the same.

Comment: What do you imagine are the logical steps necessary to solve the problem? Where did you get stuck when trying to implement it?

Comment: As i am new in the field, didn't able to find any right solutions as of now

Comment: I didn't ask you to find solutions. I asked you to think about the problem and what is involved in solving it. This is a basic skill that everyone should develop, whether they write code or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `column` let's call it a `List` or an `Array` of values.

When looking up for solving any problem, we must break it into small steps, in order to make it easier.

First of all, you'll need to create a cycle that reads the full list, one element at a time. Like this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

# Using for loop
for position in list:
    print(position)
```

While we are reading the list, our application will have 2 tasks.

- Read the current position of the list and temporarily store the value
- Replace the current position with the previous value read, until we have done it 3 times.
- 

```
input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
output_list = []

# We will store the position value here 
saved_value = 0

# We use this variable to loop to count up to 4 within the list range
counter = 0

# Using for loop
for position in input_list:
  #print(counter)

  # when the counter is zero, 
  if counter == 0:
    # we store the current position in the temporary variable
    saved_value = position

    # we add the current value of the inputlist into the output list
    output_list.append(position)
  else:
    # For every other situation we save the temporary value 
    output_list.append(saved_value)

  # increase the counter at the end of the cycle
  counter+=1

  #  every 4 reads we reset the counter  
  if counter == 4:
    counter = 0

print("\nOutput List") 
print(output_list)
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 17]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but not getting the desired output

Comment: I explained the exercise correctly, you probably didn't even bothered to copy the full solved exercise, and that is why you think the solution is wrong... 
Check again, and this time, copy everything... :S